# How to trigger form actions via PHP?

Tags: php, html, forms

I have a form which can trigger either paypal or other link.

How can I trigger those actions via PHP?

HTML:

```
<form action="myphp.php" method="POST />
  <input type="submit" value="paypal" name="action1" />
  <input type="submit" value="other" name="action2">
</form>
```

myphp.php:

```
if($_POST["action1"]) {
//https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr should trigger here
}
if($_POST["action2"]) {
//https://www.someotherwebsite.com/pay should trigger here
}
```

Comment: this question is not very clear, what do you mean by "trigger"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use :

```
if($_POST["action1"]) {
header('Location: https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr');
exit;//it's a good habit to call exit after header function because script don't stop executing after redirection
}
```

Comment: But how do you provide $_POST[''] values?

Comment: @ScottyBlades Those values are what you sent from the form to the server.

Answer (score 0):

just use `header`:

```
header('Location: http://www.example.com/');
```

Answer (score 0):

In php you can do that with `header()` method:

```
if($_POST["action1"]) {
   header('Location: https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr');
}
if($_POST["action2"]) {
   header('Location: https://www.someotherwebsite.com/pay');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a hidden input.

```
<form action="myphp.php" name="form1" method="POST" />
   <input type="hidden" name="action" />
   <input onclick="setHidden(this)" type="button" value="paypal" />
   <input onclick="setHidden(this)" type="button" value="other" />
</form>

<script>
    function setHidden(element) {
       document.form1.action.value = element.value;
       document.form1.submit();
    }
 </script>
```

Then in PHP

```
if($_POST["action"] == "paypal") {
    header('Location: https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr');
}
else if($_POST["action"] == "other") {
    header('Location: https://www.someotherwebsite.com/pay');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just check if present `isset`:

```
if(isset($_POST["action1"])) {
//https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr should trigger here
}
if(isset($_POST["action2"])) {
//https://www.someotherwebsite.com/pay should trigger here
}
```